# New SL6 system: No hostname?

Tags: networking, rhel, hostname, scientific-linux

This is in regards to Scientific Linux 6.1 system, but should also apply to CentOS 6.1 & RHEL 6.1.

I am setting up a new Scientific Linux 6.1 system, using kickstart and DHCP (via xCAT). This machine should be named `'host2.example.org'.

I see that some programs are unable to resolving the hostname of this system.

It seems that RedHat 6 no longer puts a hostname into `/etc/hosts` (See [bug 668830](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=668830) and RedHat KB [DOC-57321](https://access.redhat.com/kb/docs/DOC-57321) (login required)). In addition, the hostname is not defined in `/etc/sysconfig/network`.

```
# cat /etc/hosts
127.0.0.1   localhost localhost.localdomain localhost4 localhost4.localdomain4
::1         localhost localhost.localdomain localhost6 localhost6.localdomain6
# cat /etc/sysconfig/network
NETWORKING=yes
HOSTNAME=localhost.localdomain
# hostname
host2
# hostname --long
hostname: Host name lookup failure
```

I was expecting to see the hostname in `/etc/sysconfig/network` , but it's not there. Shouldn't something (like NetworkManager) put the hostname into a file somewhere? If so, why is there no HOSTNAME line in my `/etc/sysconfig/network`? Should Kickstart or Anaconda do this?

For CentOS/SL 5.6, I believe the hostname was always added to `/etc/hosts`.

Answer (score 1):

I also had this problem -- SL6.2 didn't set the hostname correctly at boot, which prevented all sorts of things from working.  I finally changed this line in /etc/sysconfig/network  to specify the desired host.domain name instead of "localhost.localdomain":

```
HOSTNAME=localhost.localdomain
```

That seems to do the trick.  I won't bother to try to find out why this is not done automagically during installation....